# Python String Checksum Calculator

Tags: python, encryption, hash

I managed to come up with a code to calculate the file checksum. Below is the code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import *

def get_file_checksum(filename):
    h = SHA384.new()
    chunk_size = 8192
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            h.update(chunk)
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Now I thought of another function to calculate the checksum of any given string. Here is the code

```
def get_string_checksum(string):
    h = SHA384.new()
    h.update(string)
    return h.hexdigest()
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the output of the string checksum does not match that of the file contents.

For a particular file on my system i get these values

`get_file_checksum(filename)` will get:

```
d57eec87df9c5ec33baab34be4ac7695a59d80779d10e8920640fac62f4bfa2b0da0cef0b0d7d6d1e16cae5ca560cd95
```

`get_string_checksum(string)` will get:

```
18044418f40f12e9601d0f15a7da46c114779ac337fd8fe513a122e2aa95a9b5e05d6b00d46d0682c0054c5f2b3355c0
```

The string that I used an an argument is the same as the contents of the file.

I'm using this website to verify the checksums: https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm#checksums

Is there something wrong with `get_string_checksum(string)`?

Comment: Check for trailing new line. It would make the results completely different.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for a prompt response. I checked both the file and the string, there is no any empty new line. I even updated the code with the `strip()` e.g. `h.update(string.strip())` and `h.update(chunk.strip())` but the results are still different.

However, something strange is happening though. If I print the length of the contents of the file, and the length of the string just before `h.update(string.strip())`, I expect the string lenghts to be the same but are different also.

Comment: They yield different checksums because you are inputting the strings from memory. Try to read the string from the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the white space in your file reading function like:

```
def get_file_checksum(filename):
    h = SHA384.new()
    chunk_size = 8192
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size).strip()
            if not chunk:
                break
            h.update(chunk)
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple 8-bit XOR checksum:

```js
str = "+12.2/-20.4/374/86/-12/11611/-1250/6.12347/-75.123456/85/12/-5.5/-1.2/5/6218"
let cs = 0;
for (let char of str)
    cs ^= char.charCodeAt(0)
console.log(cs.toString(16))
```

It basically takes the string and gets the XOR checksum, in this case I got =  **14** if you change a single number it changes the checksum.

Source= [8-bit XOR checksum StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328603/8-bit-xor-checksum-using-javascript)