# How to calculate the CheckSum 8 Xor

Tags: javascript, node.js, checksum

I have an example string:

```
 var string= ">ACK;ID=1206;#01D4;";
```

I need to calculate CheckSum 8 Xor so that it returns me 2 digits in hex:

**answer: 2B**

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Please show the actual string in a string format. I do not get 2b if I calculate the checksum on `>ACK;ID=1206;#01D4` or on `ACK;ID=1206;#01D4`

Comment: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328603/8-bit-xor-checksum-using-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: The estring and the one that I put in the example, I got the result after calculating in an online calculator and in 8bits it was 2B

Comment: What is the actual string. *I* added the quotes - are they added correctly? `>ACK;ID=1206;#01D4` is your string?

Comment: yes this is the string     >ACK;ID=1206;#01D4

Comment: Show me the place where you got 2B

Comment: I inserted an image of the calculator

Comment: Your string is `>ACK;ID=1206;#01D4;` not `>ACK;ID=1206;#01D4`

Comment: So it IS a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328603/8-bit-xor-checksum-using-javascript - why did you not try that?

Comment: I tried even more so I did not validate and it presents me differently, it simply converts all the characters to hex and returns me

Comment: Good afternoon folks
Thanks in advance for the attention of all, but I have succeeded with the example of the link below, thank you already.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328603/8-bit-xor-checksum-using-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Feel free to delete